# How planing about backup log files in Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, logging

In my company, we have lots of applications running in lots of different servers.
These applications generates lots of logs, which sometimes the developers forgot to compress this logs, this way **nagios** alert about disk space many times.
Beside the fact that I had to check if these logs are **compressed** and they're old than **x** days, I have to send these files to our backup server, which is gonna be in amazon, we choose this approach 'cause if some disk is full we just add a new disk on it.

So I have to create a good planning of logs.
I wonder if you guys already pass through this problem and what you recommend me to do ?
Is my approach good or bad ? Any advice would be very important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of logrotate, cron and rsync should do the job just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Configure `logrotate` or something similar properly for your environment.
2. Determine if you need to keep backups of log files.
   If so, include them in your backup process like they're any other file you need to back up.

Determining "proper" configuration for log rotation and setting up backups are left as an exercise for the reader (Server Fault can't do that for you).